# DDD: Break the domain into sub domains in different assemblies

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design

I have a domain that includes 2 sub domains.

Each sub domain includes some dependencies on the other one.

I want to put each of which sub domains into a separate assembly (I wanna split it into `1st:vertical 2nd: horizontal  modules` `=>` easy `reusability`).

And the problem is :

**How can I manage dependencies across different `sub domains` (which each of which is placed into a separate assembly)**

and

**Am I on the right path?**

Comment: Can you show some code samples?

Comment: Sub domains contact each other via identities

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One important property of a Domain is that your Domain should not depend on anything else. 
If you say that your Domain depends on some other Domain, then perhaps more analysis is required and currently identified boundaries are wrong.

**Domain speaks only in its own terms, in its own Language! NOT in terms of other domains (because it doesn't care about them), NOT in terms of external contracts/messages (because they may change), etc.**

What probably is missing here is a Bounded Context. Problems like that often pop up when no Bounded Contexts are identified in the system before even starting refining domains.

I would recommend you to start from the beginning:

1. Identify Bounded Context in your systems. By definition they are *independent* from each other.
2. Each Bounded Context would have its own domain (if it is implemented this way, which is not necessary). This domain does not know anything outside its own "bubble" and definitely has no knowledge of other domains existence or absence.
3. When different BCs need to communicate with each other, identify the *contract*. BCs (not mentioning their domains) should not depend or have references to each other, or use each other types. Instead they depend on *contracts*.
4. *Contracts* are usually messages (however some people do other things, which hurts them from time to time)
5. Anti-Corruption Layers may be implemented on BCs boundaries. It is done exactly to protect the BC (and its domain) from the stuff from outside. ACLs job is to translate things from outside (external events, messages, calls, etc) to something the domain can understand.
6. Again, **Domain speaks only in its own terms, in its own Language! NOT in terms of other domains (because it doesn't care about them), NOT in terms of external contracts/messages (because they may change), etc.**

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Did your subdomain are a Bounded Context (BC) ?

It depends and hard to help you without the real Domain, but differents BC should be physically seperated in different assemblies. And one context we will not have a reference to another... BC are autonomous components. The communication between contexts should be ideally asynchronous.

Comment: You can use Event/Command/message, read more here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj591572.aspx